# How to set the update panel trigger for the control inside repeater control?

Tags: triggers, updatepanel, repeater, itemtemplate, linkbutton

I've used ajax update panel in my web page. I want to set the trigger on the update panel. I have asp.net link button control placed in the asp.net repeater control. The content on the update panel should update when i click on the link button from repeater control. I used onclick event of the link button. Then how to set the trigger in this case?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by using following way-

```
protected void rptPagerCustomerUp_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("lnkPage") as LinkButton;
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);  
}
```